# Finding an item in a list of lists that can contain many levels

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.4.72
```

I have the following class that contains a list. However, the list will contain another list and could be 3 or 4 levels deep.

I am populating the data structure like this. And have a method to find a item from one of the children.

```
data class Producer(
        val id: Int,
        val children: List<Producer> = emptyList(),
) {
    fun createProducer(src: Producer): Producer {
        return Producer(
                id = src.id,
                children = src.children.map {
                    createProducer(it)
                }
        )
    }

    fun findProducerByIDorNull(id: Int): Producer? {
        val producer = children.firstOrNull {
            it.id == id
        }

        return producer
    }
}
```

Currently I am using `firstOrNull`. However, that will only find the item in the 1st level. If the item is at a 3 level it will return null.

Just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the point of `createProducer` here. It just converts existing producers into... producers again? Its only point is to make a deep copy?

Comment: Its like a recursive call to populate the lists. Actually this data would come from an endpoint API. I showed this so you can get the bigger picture. However, once the list have been populated. I will need to find certain producers.

Comment: It doesn't populate anything really as it's written here, it just copies existing contents. But I guess this is not the real code, and it's not really important for the question anyway.

Comment: I didn't post the code that populates as I just wanted to keep it simple. And just show the data class and the find I was using.

Comment: What you have there is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)); they're very common data structures, and you'll find lots of information about them all over the web.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `findProducerByIDOrNull` recursive. Something like:

```kotlin
    fun findProducerByIDorNull(id: Int): Producer? {
        if (this.id == id) {
            return this
        }
        return children.asSequence()
            .mapNotNull { it.findProducerByIDorNull(id) }
            .firstOrNull()
    }
```